# How to Login without using Django default login form?

Tags: python, django

I have create my own login page and i want to know how can i login into that.
I have tried this.

**Login.html**

```
   <form action="{% url 'success' %}" id="Myform">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>Username:
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Username" id="input" name="userUsername">
            </label><br>

            <label>Password:
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" id="input" name="userPassword">
            </label><br>

            <a href="{% url 'register' %}" style="float: right;">Didn't Have Account?</a><br><br>

            <button class="btn-success" id="button">Log In</button>
   </form>
```

**View.py**

```
def registerUser(request):
    username = request.POST['username']  #this LOC  is generating the error 
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']

    salt = os.urandom(32)
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
        'sha256',
        password.encode('utf-8'),
        salt,
        100000)
    hashPassword = salt + key
    context = {
        'username': username
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User(username=username, email=email, password=password, hashedPassword=hashPassword)
        user.save()
        return render(request, "success.html", context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Username already Exists")

def loginCredentials(request):

    username = request.POST["userUsername"]
    password = request.POST['userPassword']

    salt = os.urandom(32)
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
    'sha256',
    password.encode('utf-8'),
    salt,
    100000)
    hashPassword = salt + key

    checkUsername = User.objects.get(username=username)
    checkPassword = User.objects.get(hashedPassword=hashPassword)
    if checkUsername and checkPassword:
        return render(request, "success.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")
```

after running the app i am getting this **Error**

> django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'username'
>
> [09/May/2020 17:03:27] "GET/success/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=ORQBKajE1Ezzk0PeoWkUMxc3nUBbJ8g29I6MsMElyXbT8C8CjA2uoi9wdR7Z6hpd&userUsername=harshashra&userPassword=qwerty HTTP/1.1" 500 79237

So, what i wanna know is that how can i solve this error and login through my custom login form

Comment: You're trying to get 'username' from request.POST but have called it 'userUsername'

Comment: There are 2 different functions please check it.

Comment: They are separate functions but they refer to the same HTML, right?

Comment: @0sVoid No, there are different different html pages for login and Register

Comment: You've only posted the login.html, could you post the other one if you still need help with it?